# It is not appending the variable

Tags: php, javascript

I want to append the name of the file which has been uploaded using the `$_POST` method to post the `$_FILES['fileImage']['name']` from the php script. Problem is that after the file has been uploaded, I don't see the filename appended, it just shows a blank. Why is it not appending the file's name after succesful upload of the file?

If anyone could provide a coded example then it would be very helpful.

Below is Javascript code:

```
   <?php
    session_start();

    $output = array();
    if(isset($_POST['fileImage'])){
        $idx = count($_POST['fileImage']) -1 ;
        $output[] = isset($_POST['fileImage'][$idx]) ?
            $_POST['fileImage'][$idx]['name'] : "";
    }

    ?>

     <script>   


    function stopImageUpload(success) {
        var imageNameArray = <?php echo  json_encode($output); ?>;
        var result = '';

        if (success == 1) {
            result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
            for (var i = 0; i < imageNameArray.length; i++) {
                $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i] + '<br/>');
            }
        }
        else {
            result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
        }

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Below is the php script which uploads the  file and this script is on a seperate age from the Javascript function:

```
 <?php
session_start();

$result = 0;
$errors = array ();
$dirImage = "ImageFiles/";

if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) &&
    $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];

    $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );

    $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

    if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
        if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
            $result = 1;
        }
    }
}

$_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = array('name' => $_FILES ['fileImage']['name']);
?>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the form that uploads the file? (And any related JS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're looking in `$_POST` for a variable which is in `$_SESSION`. Try changing it to:

```
$output = array();
if(isset($_SESSION['fileImage'])){
    $idx = count($_SESSION['fileImage']) -1 ;
    $output[] = isset($_SESSION['fileImage'][$idx]) ?
        $_SESSION['fileImage'][$idx]['name'] : "";
}
```

Comment: OK, $_SESSION does make the file name appear but it is the wrong file name which is why I didn't want to use $_SESSION. What happens is that imagine I uploaded the file dog.png, the file name that it is suppose to append dog.png is actually blank. Now I refresh the browser. Now when I upload another file (cat.png), after upload is successful it appends file name dog.png and not cat.png. How can this be fixed if you know?